# Converting a date and and a char 'time' field to a single date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concatenate two fields and load the data into a date field.

I have a table with `hier_dt` as `DATE` datatype and `hier_tm` as `CHAR` datatype, with data like:

```
hier_dt   | hier_tm
16-JAN-17 | 16:54
16-JAN-17 | 16:54
16-JAN-17 | 16:54
16-JAN-17 | 16:54
17-JAN-17 | 17:54
```

I would like to concatenate both of these into a single `DATE` datatype field, to produce:

```
hier_dt_tm
----------------
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/17 17:54
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

My current query is:

```
select to_date(concat(to_char(NVL(hier_DT,'01-JAN-1900'), 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
  concat(' ',NVL(hier_tm,'00:00'))), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') as temp 
from XXX1
```

Comment: I hadn't looked at your query attempt closely; it seems to work already, so what are you looking for - a better or clearer way? Or do you have an issue with the null values (which I'd overlooked, as you don't have any in your sample data and results)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight variation on the other ideas is to leave `hier_dt` as a date, and figure out the fraction of a day that `hier_tm` represents. One way to do that is to convert just the time to a date - which defaults everything else to the first of the current month - and subtract the first from that, then add the result to `hier_dt`:

```
hier_dt + (to_date(hier_tm, 'HH24:MI') - trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
```

With explicit formatting back to a string just for display purposes:

```
select to_char(
    hier_dt + (to_date(hier_tm, 'HH24:MI') - trunc(sysdate, 'MM')),
    'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') as temp
from xxx1;

TEMP            
----------------
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/17 17:54
```

Yet another way is to convert the time to an interval datatype using the `to_dsinterval()` function, which involves tacking on dummy day and second values to make the string something that function recognises:

```
hier_dt + to_dsinterval('0 ' || hier_tm || ':00')
```

Without explicit conversion to string this time, relying instead on NLS settings:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI';

select hier_dt + to_dsinterval('0 ' || hier_tm || ':00') as temp
from xxx1;

TEMP            
----------------
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/16 16:54
2017/01/17 17:54
```

For me, this approach is the most obvious in terms of understanding what the code is trying to do, though the concatenation still makes it not completely obvious at first glance, perhaps.

---

The query attempt in the question seems to work, aside from relying on your NLS settings and implicit conversion of `'01-JAN-1900'` to a date; but it can be simplified, and I'd still prefer my approach (obviously!). I'd missed the handling for null values though. So, versions handling null values in either column:

```
select coalesce(hier_dt, date '1900-01-01')
  + case when hier_tm is null then 0 
      else (to_date(hier_tm, 'HH24:MI') - trunc(sysdate, 'MM')) end as temp
from xxx1;
```

or

```
select coalesce(hier_dt, date '1900-01-01')
  + to_dsinterval('0 ' || coalesce(hier_tm, '00:00') || ':00') as temp
from xxx1;
```

Comment: showing in the desired format is easy as this `to_char(hier_tm,'yyyy/mm/dd ')||hier_dt` but to make it `date` we need setting of `nls_date_format` as Alex told.

Comment: The question says the desired result is "a single DATE datatype", so I've done that in both versions; I've only used `nls_date_format` for display in the second example as an alternative to the explicit `to_char()`. Neither of the conversion *to* a date rely on NLS settings though. (Also you have your `tm` and `dt` reversed *8-)

Comment: Instead of subtracting `trunc(sysdate, 'mm')` (which requires you to remember that `to_date()` with a time-of-day argument defaults to the first day of the current month - not to "today" and not to the first day of the current year), one could subtract `to_date('00:00', 'HH24:MI')`. That should produce the correct result regardless of defaults, as long as the defaults are applied consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 SELECT
 /* TO_DATE( */
  TO_CHAR(hier_dt, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || 
  ' ' ||
  hier_tm
 /* ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') */
 AS HIER_dt_tm
 FROM temp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f69b/35

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert it to `DATE`.

```
SELECT  
   TO_DATE(  TO_CHAR(hier_dt,'DD-MON-YYYY') || hier_tm , 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ) HIER_dt 
 FROM Yourtable;
```

Use this to display it in your desired format.

```
 SELECT  
  TO_CHAR (  TO_DATE(  TO_CHAR(hier_dt,'DD-MON-YYYY') || hier_tm , 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ),
           'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') hier_dt_tm
 FROM Yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78ba2/12)

Comment: Hi kaushik,It says literal doesn't match format string error ORA -01861

Comment: @beckham : Modified. try now

Comment: Not sure why you'd use a 2-digit YY model (ever, any more...). If any of the original dates aren't in the current century then the result will be wrong?

Comment: Downvoted because of Alex's point.  You risk losing century data by doing it this way.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus : Corrected now. It was a mistake.